# zend regex route with negative lookahead

Tags: regex, zend-framework, zend-route

I'm trying to write a regex route in zend (1.11) that matches urls ending in /foo but not if they start with /bar
e.g.

```
/foo - match
/any/words/foo - match

/any/words - no match (doesn't end in /foo)
/any/words/barfoo - no match (doesn't end in /foo)
/bar/foo - no match (starts with /bar)
/bar/any/words/foo - no match (starts with /bar)
```

my regext route looks like this:

```
'^foo$|^(?!/bar/).+/foo$'
```

But I find it matches anything ending in /foo, even if it starts with /bar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Final solution:**

```
'^foo$|^(?!bar).*/foo$'
```

**Explanation**
The regex was a red-herring, this was more of a zend problem. My problem was that the url string that is passed to Zend doesn't contain a leading slash, so I was testing regex against the wrong input. So in my solution I need to look for '^foo$' to match '/foo' OR '^(?!bar).*/foo$' to match '/any/words/foo' excluding '/bar/any/words/foo'.

Special thanks however to @zx81 for an amazingly fast and detailed response, and helping un-block my thinking. I'd recommend reading his response above for reference.

Answer (score 1):

**You Need a Negative Lookahead**

Lucky for you, I have one in my pocket. Try this:

```
^(?!/bar).*/foo$
```

See what matches [in the demo](http://regex101.com/r/nF6bT6).

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- The negative lookahead `(?!/bar)` asserts that what follows is not `/bar`
- `.*` matches any characters (dot is any character except newlines, the star repeats it zero or more times)
- `/foo` matches `/foo`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Thanks for the amazing speedy response. However it doesn't seem to work as a zend regex route. I'm fairly sure my regex does the job (will test in http://regex101.com/), but in the zend regex route context, it still matches urls starting with /bar. I'm doing more tests now...

Comment: Aha - I think I may have found it. (?!bar).*/foo - the leading slash is not passed as part of the string to match. More tests and confirmation to follow!

Comment: Mmm, the regex is correct, why would it not work? Here are two explanations I can think of: (i) no support for lookahead, or (ii) the regex uses a `/` delimiter, so the `/` inside would have to be escaped

Comment: Looks like our messages crossed paths... What you found is consistent with my idea #2... In which case (i) change the delimiter if possible, or (ii) escape the slashes in the regex: `^(?!\/bar).*\/foo$` (same as in regex101)